# MOSFET is (probably) on but current isn't flowing

Tags: mosfet, powermosfet

I have a N-type enhancement MOSFET ([IRF740](https://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irf740.pdf)) by which I am trying to power a relay.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIZz9S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am powering the MOSFET with Arduino's 5V output. The actual gate-source voltage is measured as 4,95V.

When I apply gate voltage, I am measuring 40 Ohm across D and S when D is disconnected from the circuit [pic. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2t8rE.jpg), and infinity when I connect D to 5V [pic. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZrLa.jpg).

Sometimes D - S resistance even oscillates between 10 Ohm and infinity approx.every second.

But the main problem is that I am only getting 0,5 mA from D to S, even when shorted.
[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKqT8.jpg)

According to the datasheet, I should be getting 700 mA with this gate voltage.
[image]

I don't know if the MOSFET is blown or I am being oblivious to something sipmle.

This is my Arduino code:

```
#define MOSFET_PIN 6

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(MOSFET_PIN,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(MOSFET_PIN,HIGH);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: The circuit and measurements performed on it make no sense. You are trying to short circuit 5V to ground through the FET directly and also through the multimeter to measure current. The FET can now be damaged and multimeter may now have a blown fuse. Usinh a multimeter for measuring resistance of something that is not a resistance will give bogus results. Can you clarify what question you are asking?

Comment: Please put up a full circuit diagram showing all connections to the Arduino board and where your load resistor is connected. There is a circuit diagram tool in the editor.

Comment: @Justme my question is why there is such a small current flowing through the FET. Initially, I have measured the current with a series resistor, and I gradually reduced the resistance to none to see if the current would increase, but it did not.

Comment: @Atropin Then you should have mentioned it. Because all we saw were the pics and their descriptions. Pic 2 will cause the FET to damage, and Pic 3 will cause multimeter 400mA fuse to blow up if the FET was working and circuit was operating as expected.

Comment: @Justme Sorry if that was confusing. So it seems like the FET is probably damaged, that's why the strange behavior?

Comment: @Atropin Well you need to verify it is or if there are just bad connections somewhere. How much current the relay draws, what make/model the relay is?

Comment: @Justme It is HK4100F. With 160 Ohm coil resistance (measured) it should be able to draw 31,25 mA at 5V. I'm just assuming the transistor is dead, need to get a new one.

Comment: Why are you testing the circuit with no load? Your pictures show the Arduino +5 V connected directly to the drain pin. Your schematic includes a relay as the main load. At the very least if the MOSFET was working correctly you would have shorted the +5 V output. The MOSFET being a high current part may survive such a short as your USB is likely not capable of supplying that much current. As in other comments, recheck all your connections, breadboard sockets and jumper pins can at times be unreliable. Try installing the MOSFET directly into the breadboard rather then on external pins/sockets.